# How to stop the program in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

How to stop the program in prolog? Like if I want to do:

```
stop(X) :- X =:= 0 -> // (stop the program).
```

Comment: The question would be "why do you want to stop the program?" It sounds like there's a design issue with your code if you want to forcibly stop it. What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use halt/0 predicate:

```
stop(X) :- X =:= 0 -> halt.
```